# How can I specify a maximum or minimum number with AJV for JSON Type Definition (JTD)?

Tags: node.js, json, ajv

How can I specify a maximum or minimum number with AJV for JSON Type Definition (JTD)?

I don't see anywhere in the docs how to specify.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @JamieHall, I never did. If you want a TypeScript friendly validator (with this feature) then I'd recommend: https://github.com/colinhacks/zod

Answer (score 3):

You need to look for keyword for numbers in docs
https://ajv.js.org/json-schema.html#keywords-for-numbers

```
{type: "number", maximum: 5}
```

or

```
{type: "number", exclusiveMinimum: 5}
```

Comment: This is for JSON Schema. My question is about JSON Type Definition

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: there is no way.

The standard itself (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8927) doesn't support any kind of content validation, despite the type of data.

However, it is possible to extend the syntax with metadata (read https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8927#name-extending-jtds-syntax), and the library to recognize it.

For example:

```
...
{ 
    "elements": { 
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": { 
            "minElements": 1, 
            "maxElements": 10, 
            "uniqueElements": true, 
            "regex": "[a-z]*" 
        }
    }
} 
...
```

Not the best solution, but maybe an opportunity for agreeing on a well-known extension language.